# how do i resolve invalid number ORA-06512 error in this in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table Cliente
(
  CLienteID number(1) not null,
  ClienteNombre Varchar2(30) not null,
  ClienteDireccion Varchar2(1000) not null,
  ClienteCiudad smallint not null,
  constraint pkCliente primary key (ClienteID)
);

insert into Cliente (CLienteID, ClienteNombre, ClienteDireccion, ClienteCiudad)
    values (1, 'Pablo Paredes', 'Cuarta terraza', 'Puerto Montt');
```

Comment: You declared `ClienteCiudad` as `smallint`.  You should not be surprised that inserting a string causes a problem.

Comment: Moreover, I would suggest to use simple native `number(38,0)` in this case, instead of using PL/SQL `sys.standard.smallint` which is translated to `number(38,0)` in `SQL` (SQL types are not always equal to PL/SQL types!): `select line,text from dba_source where owner='SYS' and name='STANDARD' and type='PACKAGE' and lower(text) like '%smallint%'; ` Results: ` subtype SMALLINT is NUMBER(38,0);`

Comment: more about this difference: http://orasql.org/2012/11/10/differences-between-integerint-in-sql-and-plsql/

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon stated, you are trying to insert a string "Puerto Montt" into a column declared as numeric datatype.

Changing the column ClienteCiudad to a varchar2 solves your issue:

```
create table Cliente
(
  CLienteID number(1) not null,
  ClienteNombre Varchar2(30) not null,
  ClienteDireccion Varchar2(1000) not null,
  ClienteCiudad varchar2(100) not null,
  constraint pkCliente primary key (ClienteID)
);
```

You'll only be able to add single-digit client IDs in a number(1) column.